# TypeScript lowercase string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to make sure that TS ***will*** scream if it receives something else from lowercase string for `fieldName`?

```
type Props = {
  onEdit: (data: Record<string, string | number>) => void;
  title: string;
  fields: {
    fieldName: string;
    fieldValue?: string | number;
   }
};
```

Comment: Probably not since "lowercase" isn't a type. --- That being said, there does seem to be a thing called "refinement types"? https://lemoine-benoit.medium.com/refinement-types-in-typescript-or-how-to-check-that-a-number-must-be-positive-at-compile-time-342c1e6e90e

Comment: in typescript 4.1+ you can tediously make an interface that only has lowercase letters in `|` , documentation here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Comment: If that property is assigned anything other than a compile time constant, definitely impossible. A better question is why you need to encode that particular constraint in the type system?

Comment: `fieldName.toLowerCase() === fieldName`. Or write 30 lines of overkill typing nonsense.

Comment: To further what @morganney says, your TS code will be Javascript at runtime, and possibly have to interface with non-TS JS code as well. Types are nice, but in addition to the hit to readability you are to some degree tilting with windmills if you attempt to do too much in TS's type system. Don't let it lull you into a false sense of security about runtime checks on invariants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of TypeScript 4.8 there is now support for using [the intrinsic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types) with wide types like `string`.  This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47050) but not mentioned in the [TS 4.8 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/).

So now, `Lowercase<string>` only corresponds to lowercase strings (strings which remain unchanged after `.toLowerCase()`), whereas in TypeScript 4.7 and below it could match any `string`:

```
type Props = {
    onEdit: (data: Record<string, string | number>) => void;
    title: string;
    fields: {
        fieldName: Lowercase<string>;
        fieldValue?: string | number;
    }
};

const p: Props = {
    onEdit() { },
    title: "ABC",
    fields: {
        fieldName: "okay"  // okay      
    }
}
p.fields.fieldName = "Oops" // error! Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Lowercase<string>'
p.fields.fieldName = "123" // okay, Lowercase<"123"> is "123"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwLACgoFQIB2AogCYCWwAXFABTkCGwTdAShAMYJzkA8yYHErEA5gBooQkeKgAfKMQCuAWwBGEOAD4AlOm1QAbgkrkA3HkJRg1ADYQ6M0WMv5CAM0oQ75ZHRx3awIvH3IAOSZVRygAGQQAdy0uJmQIQWEXbTdgz29fADUmO2UIAH4nTLlFFQ0tHMIAXzxGtzweYiEoMDp4JFQMQOsSCmp6fUwoRokrQltgBzoAIgBBACEAYSWZoKhQ338sWdz9iKiYpYQAayYQJYIAegeiG5Bc46mWvDAAOlPkP75M7RdBQJYAeX69yeUC0iDgAEIoAAVcDQADkznE6KglFQxAQwCgqWQlDExCY6gcNgQNjRUHR8SScBSaQysjE2nR30BYQBp0iIIwSwAjAAmADM0Oe11uUiZyVS6VFkqWhjxYPFUqAA)

Answer (score 3):

It's simple enough to create a utility to enforce that string literals are lowercase using the type utility [`Lowercase<StringType>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#lowercasestringtype):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgMwPYCcDGEAySDuEUDCAhgM4QA8AKlBAB7ARwAmJUJwKAlnAOYB8UALxRsedKQqUBdBs1bUA-AFgAUFDYduPGvUYsoiqHAgA3fFABcB1eqvGzKANw2oq0JCgBlDgEYhsRFQMUXxiMnIAcgAJCAAbWKQIvkcoAHpUo1N8N3BobxQAJn94ZHQsXFCJSIALOISklPSoACJa+KRm1SA)

```ts
type EnforceLowerCase<T extends string> = Lowercase<T> extends T ?
  string extends T ? never : T
  : never;
  
type Str1 = EnforceLowerCase<'Hello'>; // never
type Str2 = EnforceLowerCase<'hello'>; // "hello"
```

However, using it in your scenario would be very convoluted, because it would require using only string literals (which TS doesn't infer on object property values).

---

Instead, it's better to ensure conformance of the expectation at runtime. Here's an example using a pure function which doesn't mutate the input object:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=28&ssc=71&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwLACgpQIB2AogCYCWwAXFABRkCGwjtAShAMYJxkA8yYHApEA5gBoog4WKgAfKEQCuAWwBGEOAD4AlOi1QAbggpkA3HgLAqAGwi1pI0RfxQAZhQg2yyWjlcEHl5kAHKMKvZSQk4uBIGe3gBqjDZKEAD8DtGyCsrqmrFQAL4uRXh4bkpEnNbEUBBEyEpwEAAyCADumgDCjMgQAGIJoeHQdGCIKLTwSMg605Oo-gQtwM1EWAB02xOzkkHevliWcdubuyibBz7iJ-HBYRG0F8hXw6-XjxCbwAjtnCk2p0en0IHQdLdXEUSngyrgKlUahQ6mQEABlBARYAACycAHUqNiZih6C8FrM9MsXuh6o1mkCunBev0hg9RuNFjpYtxGgg7JsbAhRByKaVyrgeYIoGTYIsactCKRKDQoEwWPosEVIVZbJEAOTWYB2PXa9zvPyfUa0PUACS8gr1WthLjwqIxWNxYgJOOJyBFKC5UAA9EGttt9uasGa2U8oAAibH2hBx4rFPBAA)

```ts
function ensureLowerCaseFieldName (props: Props): Props {
  return {...props, fields: {
    ...props.fields,
    fieldName: props.fields.fieldName.toLocaleLowerCase(),
  }};
}

function doSomethingWithProps (props: Props) {
 props = ensureLowerCaseFieldName(props);
 console.log(props);
}

const props: Props = {
  onEdit: data => {},
  title: 'title',
  fields: {fieldName: 'Hello'},
};

doSomethingWithProps(props); // {..., fields: { fieldName: "hello" } }
```